# Unable to understand precision and scale of numeric datatype in DBMS

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sqldatatypes

If we specify column as decimal(5,2), which means we have precision is 5 and scale is 2.
If I understand it correctly, precision is maximum number of digits in a number and scale is maximum number of digits that can be present to the right of the decimal point.
So from this logic if I try to insert 100.999 it should fail as scale is 3 for this number which is not allowed. But when I am using online edition such as:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php
https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql
and running following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE nd (nv decimal(5, 2));
INSERT INTO nd VALUES(100.999);
INSERT INTO nd VALUES(1001.2);
INSERT INTO nd VALUES(10011.2);
INSERT INTO nd VALUES(100111.299999);
Select * from nd;
```

This gives me output as:

```
100.999
1001.2
10011.2
100111.2991999
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only database that would not complain and run your code is SQLite, because in SQLite there is no `DECIMAL` data type.

So, maybe you think that by defining a column as `decimal(5, 2)` you are defining the column to be *numeric* with 5 as *precision* and 2 as *scale*, but all of them are just ignored.

For SQLite you are just defining a column with `NUMERIC` affinity and nothing more.
The proper data type that you should have used is `REAL` and there is no way to define *precision* and *scale* (unless you use more complex constraints).

You can find all about SQLite's data types and affinities here: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

Those online SQL executors probably uses SQLite, which ignores the decimal and corresponding scale and precision, as @forpas said.

If you try to execute the queries in database like postgresql, you'll get the error you expected, numeric field overflows exception.
Try this [engine](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html) to execute your queries, hope you'll understand what is happening.